# What is the 'right' way to share data between node child_process event handlers?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, child-process

What is the right way to share data between the node child-process event handlers? The [child-process docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_class_childprocess) define the available events as 'close', 'disconnect', 'error', 'exit', 'message', and 'spawn', indicating that a handler can defined for each one and provides a few examples like these:

```
process.on('message', (m) => {
  console.log('CHILD got message:', m);
});

subprocess.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error('Failed to start subprocess.');
});
```

I'm looking for a way to share data between event handlers on a child-process that is forked. I've already discovered the options object letting you specify environment variables at the time that the process is spawned, like so:

```
const tableInsertionProcess = childProcess.fork(
  './recordInsertion',
  [], // no arguments
  {
    env: {
      tableName: tableName, // add tableName as environment variable to be accessible in all event handlers
      ...process.env        // process.env is the default; include it for consistency
    },
  }
)
log_info(`Spawned child process ${tableInsertionProcess.pid} for ${tableName}`)

tableInsertionProcess.send({
  notes: notes,
  inputCsv: inputCsv
})
```

Is there a way to share data between event handlers? If you consider the process/thread as an object, this would be object-level data: private fields or members. Something like the following:

```
let messagesReceived = 0;

process.on('message', (m) => {
  console.log('CHILD got message:', m);
  messagesReceived += 1;
});

process.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error(`Error after processing ${messagesReceived} messages: ${err.message}`);
});
```

Is there a better way or right way of doing this? The global variable feels wrong.

Can you alter the environment variables in one handler and have them show up in a different handler? (Seems like an anti-pattern at best.)

---

It also looks like the arguments (second parameter to `.fork()`) are available in every event handler as well using the `subprocess.spawnargs`. There are no examples of this in the docs, though. I'm also wondering, why is the event handler defined as `process.on` but all the other fields are defined on the `subprocess` variable?

---

Apologies if the [child-process](/questions/tagged/child-process) tag is misplaced. The tag description implies without explicitly stating that it's for Unix child-processes. Node's child-process docs say they try to be unix-like. Let me know and I'll remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a better way or right way of doing this?

If you're talking about accessing common data from multiple event handlers in the same child_process, then you just define module variables or some module-level data structure that both can access.  There's nothing fancy here.

Your `messagesReceived` example will work just fine.  Nothing more than that is needed.

> The global variable feels wrong.

`messagesReceived` is not a global.  It's a module level variable and this is a perfectly fine thing to do for module-level data.  There are thousands of reasons to want to keep track of module-level data.  If you want to share that data structure across modules in the same process, you can export the root of the data structure or export an object that has methods for accessing the data.  If everything is within just one module, then you can just directly access the module level data or object.

> Can you alter the environment variables in one handler and have them show up in a different handler? (Seems like an anti-pattern at best.)

There's really no reason to put stuff like this in environment variables when regular Javascript variables declared at module scope work just fine.  It's much easier to modify regular Javascript variables and program with them than to try to store modifiable data in the process environment.

> I'm also wondering, why is the event handler defined as process.on but all the other fields are defined on the subprocess variable?

This is unrelated to the other things you've asking about.  `process.on('message', (m) => {...}` is for registering an event handler for when some other process or child process sends your process a message.  So, `process` events are things that happen to YOUR process.

Event handlers from your process on a different `subprocess` or `child_process` are for getting events based on various lifetime events that occur in relation to that OTHER process.  These are things that happen to the other process (specifically things like when they exit or events related to their `stdio` and `stdin`.

> It also looks like the arguments (second parameter to .fork()) are available in every event handler)

The second argument to `.fork()` create the command line arguments passed to the child_process and they will be available within that other process as `process.argv` (if it's a nodejs app) or however command line arguments are made available if the process is created in some other programming environment.

Comment: @patrickm - Did this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.